# K8s Cluster over Azure using Kubeadm + Autoscaling using VMSS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, autoscaling, azure-vm-scale-set

I have k8s cluster running in Azure VMs with Azure as cloud provider configured using kubeadm
My goal is to add the VMSS for auto-scaling, my CA is running fine and can scale up the VMs in VMSS but it is not able to register node to the cluster.

- Updated cloud config file.
- Updated kubeadm config file.
- Updated cluster-autoscaler-vmss.yaml accordingly.

Refrence:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#im-running-cluster-with-nodes-in-multiple-zones-for-ha-purposes-is-that-supported-by-cluster-autoscaler
- https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-azure/blob/master/docs/cloud-provider-config.md
- https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/azure

cluster-autoscaler-vmss.yaml

```
            - --cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf
            - --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
            - --nodes=1:10:k8svmss 
            - --node-group-auto-discovery=label:foo=bar
```

Expect: Node to autoscale and join cluster.

Comment: are you looking to provision node level autoscaling using VMSS, which was prior working in VMs ?

Comment: @TusharMahajan I never tried using normal VMs, But yes I am trying to provision node level autoscaling using VMSS.